# How to stage, commit and push large amount of changes to GitHub through command line in Rstudio cloud?

Tags: r, github, rstudio

I have worked quite a bit in R but I am a novice to GitHub and it's integration with RStudio cloud.

I am trying to update the my git repository through RStudio cloud but couldn't do so through command line (I was able to do so in GUI though).

I have tried 
`add .`
`git add -A` after installing git2r package in the cloud, but nothing seems to work and I am kind of stuck after googling for half an hour.

Comment: please provide the error message, if you get one, from your attempts. I believe you are trying to type the commands into the `Console` instead of the `Terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to input the git commands in the Console instead of in the terminal pane. See attached image.

By the way, to avoid adding unwanted files as in the image attached, you may want to create a good `gitignore` file. See a good tutorial here [See a good tutorial from atlassian here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that. Can I perform those tasks in console or I have to write them evertime in terminal only?

Comment: Everything related to R (basically your analysis) should be typed in the console (or in the script).
git is another program altogether and you can interact with it via the terminal. by the way, if the answer "fixed" your issue, please mark as solved. You can even use the `git2r` library to interact with git via R, but unless you are doing it programmatically, I dont think it is a good idea

Comment: Thank you Marcelo. If we could interact with git using git2r, could you please enlist steps to do it programmatically for all the changes made?

Comment: yes, sure. But it would be better to open a new question detailing exactly what you want to do, so that it stays as a reference for later users with the same problem. Also, I never used this library, so I am not sure I can help. Surely some other people will.

Comment: hey @data9, if the answer is solved, it would be great if you mark it as solved :)